# Lead Conversion customization test class is showing 0% coverage

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, leads, lead-conversion, customization

```
@isTest
public class LeadConversionAutomation_Test {

    public static testmethod void TestLeadconvert (){
        
        
        Lead testLead = new Lead(LastName = 'TestLName',FirstName = 'testFName',Status='Open - Not Contacted',Company = 'testCompany', Email = 'xxxxx@xxxxx.com');
        test.startTest();
        insert testLead;
        
        System.assertEquals(testLead.FirstName, 'testFName');
        Id leadOwner = testUser.Id;
        database.LeadConvert leadConvertTest = new database.LeadConvert();
        leadConvertTest.setLeadId(testLead.Id);
        leadConvertTest.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(False);
        leadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true Limit 1];
        leadConvertTest.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
        //leadConvertTest.setConvertedStatus('Closed - Converted');
        Database.LeadConvertResult leadConvertResultTest = Database.convertLead(leadConvertTest);
        System.assert(leadConvertResultTest.isSuccess());
        
        leadConvertTest.setOpportunityName('testFName TestLName');
        test.stopTest();
       
       List<Account> accQuery = [SELECT ID, Name,OwnerId from Account where name= 'testFName TestLName'];
        for(Account acc : accQuery){
            system.assertEquals(acc.OwnerId, leadOwner);
        }
        
        
       List< Opportunity> oppQuery = [SELECT ID, Name,OwnerId from Opportunity where name= 'testFName TestLName'];
        for(Opportunity opp : oppQuery){
            system.assertEquals(opp.OwnerId, leadOwner);
        }
    }

     
   
}
```

Apex Class for custom lead conversion logic:
global class AutomatedLeadConversion {
public static void Leadconvert(List inputs){
LeadStatus convertStatus= [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true Limit 1];
List<Database.LeadConvert> listLeadconvert = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();

```
    for(Input i: inputs){
        Database.LeadConvert leadConvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
        leadConvert.setLeadId(i.record.id);
        leadConvert.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
        System.debug('Input Account Id: '+i.accountId);
        System.debug('Input Contact Id: '+i.contactId);
        if(i.accountId != NULL || i.accountId != ''){
            leadconvert.setAccountId(i.accountId);
            if(i.contactId != NULL || i.contactId != ''){
                leadconvert.setContactId(i.contactId);
            }
        }
        leadConvert.setOwnerId(UserInfo.getUserId());
        // if createOpportunity is FALSE, set DoNotCreateOpportunity flag
        if(!i.createOpportunity){
            leadConvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(TRUE);
        }
        listLeadConvert.add(LeadConvert);
    }
    
    if(!listLeadConvert.isEmpty()){
        List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.Leadconvert(listLeadConvert);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show what you are trying to test. Use the `{}` tool in the editor to format your code.

Comment: You're testing the standard Lead Conversion logic. If you want to test your customized logic, you need to call the code in that class.

Comment: If you have written custom logic in apex to covert your lead, please share that.